Configure JMeter default open folder
I wish to configure JMeter 5.6 default open folder.
By default it open in jmeter_home/bin

I did not find any GUI setting/configuration.
I asked the chat bot for any configuration property. It suggested to add into jmeter.properties:
jmeter.load.folder=D:/jmeter-5.5/test-plans/proj-1

That is not working.
Update
Thanks to @Ivan G.
Suggested property user.dir in configuration file system.properties. And restart.
user.dir=D:/jmeter-5.5/test-plans/proj-1

That is not working as well. :(
Suggestions welcome.

Looking into JMeter source code the correct property name is user.dir, it's Java System Property if you want to override it - you need to set it in system.properties file.
JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.
However changing this property may result into unexpected behaviour as it's used in multiple places.
More information: Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide
P.S. "chat bots" are basically language models, I wouldn't trust them too much

thanks for the suggestion. tested not working.
